# Add New Row to xtragrid View

Tags: devexpress

I have created Xtragrid in which i have added RepositoryItemLookUpEdit at run time but the problem is when i add a new row by using View.AddNewRow(); a new row is added with empty cell. So i need to add RepositoryItemLookUpEdit in new created row. Can any body help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. You need to use a datasource that implements IBindingList, such as BindingList **and also** set AllowNew = true

Answer (score 0):

Where do you bind the data?

Can I suggest you implement the following ex and see where the problem starts?
 *Start with a grid and button on the form. I created the repository item in the designer*

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("newTable");
    dt.Columns.Add("1", typeof(Int32));
    dt.Columns.Add("2", typeof(bool));
    dt.Columns.Add("3", typeof(Int32));

    dt.Rows.Add(1, true, 12);
    dt.Rows.Add(2, false, 32);
    dt.Rows.Add(3, true, 42);

    gridControl1.DataSource = dt;

    gridView1.Columns[0].ColumnEdit = repositoryItemCheckEdit1;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridView1.AddNewRow();
}
```

It adds a new row with a repository item in the 1st column :)

Answer (score 0):

I always add one more item in data source, for example:

```
   private void AgregarDetalle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var list = GridOpcionDetalle.DataSource as List<DetalleOpcion>;
            list.Add(new DetalleOpcion());

            GridOpcionDetalle.DataSource = list;
            GridOpcionDetalle.RefreshDataSource();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub grdInvoice_EditorKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles grdInvoice.EditorKeyDown

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim i As Integer

    With GridView1
        .OptionsNavigation.EnterMoveNextColumn = True
        If e.KeyData = "13" Or e.KeyData = "9" Then
            If .FocusedRowHandle.ToString = .RowCount - 1 Then
                If .FocusedColumn Is .Columns("Rate") Then
                    If .GetRowCellValue(.RowCount - 1, "Qty") <> "0" And .GetRowCellValue(.RowCount - 1, "Rate") <> "0" And .GetRowCellValue(.RowCount - 1, "ItemCode") <> "" Then
                        dt.Columns.Add("No")
                        dt.Columns.Add("ItemCode")
                        dt.Columns.Add("ItemName")
                        dt.Columns.Add("Qty")
                        dt.Columns.Add("Rate")
                        dt.Columns.Add("Amount")
                        dt.Columns.Add("Unit")
                        For i = 0 To .RowCount - 1
                            dr = dt.NewRow
                            dr("No") = .GetRowCellValue(i, "No")
                            dr("ItemCode") = .GetRowCellValue(i, "ItemCode")
                            dr("ItemName") = .GetRowCellValue(i, "ItemName")
                            dr("Rate") = .GetRowCellValue(i, "Rate")
                            dr("Qty") = .GetRowCellValue(i, "Qty")
                            dr("Amount") = .GetRowCellValue(i, "Amount")
                            dr("Unit") = .GetRowCellValue(i, "Unit")
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                        Next
                        dr = dt.NewRow
                        dr("No") = .GetRowCellValue(i - 1, "No") + 1
                        dr("ItemCode") = ""
                        dr("ItemName") = ""
                        dr("Rate") = "0"
                        dr("Qty") = "0"
                        dr("Amount") = "0"
                        dr("Unit") = ""
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                        grdInvoice.DataSource = dt
                        .FocusedRowHandle = i
                        .FocusedColumn = .Columns("ItemCode")
                    End If
                End If

            End If
        End If
    End With
```